# Как управлять позициями между объектами

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть два объекта, один подвижный, второй нет. Мне нужно чтобы второй объект имел те же позиции что и первый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый объект это подвижный, а второй нет.

Этот скрипт относиться к первому объекту.

```
    public class EnemyLogic : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject objectsEnemy;
    GameObject bullet;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        Debug.Log(pos.x + " " + pos.y + " " + pos.z);
        var objectsEnemys = objectsEnemy.GetComponent<BulletLogic>();
        objectsEnemys.setPositionsVector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);

        Instantiate(objectsEnemy);

    }

    // Update is called once per frameЫ
    void Update () {
       // Destroy(GameObject.Find("bullet(Clone)"));
        if (GameObject.Find("Bullet(Clone)") == null)
        {
            Instantiate(objectsEnemy);
        }
    }
}
```

В методе `Srart()` я получаю текущие координаты врага, а после передаю эти координаты в класс `BulletLogic` который управляет пулей.

```
public class BulletLogic : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 1.5f;
    public float tameFile = 1f;

   

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        tameFile -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (tameFile <= 0) {
            DestroyObject(gameObject);
        }

        transform.Translate(new Vector2(-speed, 0));
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D myCollision)
    {
        // определение столкновения с двумя разноименными объектами
        if (myCollision.gameObject.tag == "Char")
        {
             DestroyObject(gameObject);
        }
    }


public Boolean life() {
        return true;
    }


    public void setPositionsVector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        Debug.Log(x + " " + y + " " + z);
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(x, y, z));

    }
}
```

У меня не получается изменять таким образом координаты, а еще unity сохраняет прошлые координаты и к ним добавляет существующие.

Или расскажите как взаимодействовать между объектами через скрипты.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.

```
public void setPositionsVector3(float x, float y, float z) {
    Debug.Log(x + " " + y + " " + z);
    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```